# Appropriate Installation Directory

Tags: windows, installation

I have a program which needs installing on windows 64 boxes.  Most of the application has been ported to 64 bit but there are still one or two minor modules which we haven't ported mostly due to third party dependencies.  Where should I install this programme? C:\program files (x86) or c:\program files?  Because it is a mixture I am leaning towards c:\program files but perhaps there is a standard about which I am unaware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install to "C:\Program Files"

There is no standard for putting mixed stuff like that in (x86).

If it were mostly x86 still I would probably say otherwise, but from the sounds of it you don't have much there that is still x86, correct?

Comment: Just use Program Files then since it's, generally speaking, a 64 bit app.